# What does CMFCButton::EnableFullTextTooltip do?

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

I was trying the `CMFCButton` tooltips and found that if I call `EnableFullText()` the tooltips don't show.

Here's a little sample:

```
// In OnInitDialog()
c_MyBtn.m_nFlatStyle = CMFCButton::BUTTONSTYLE_SEMIFLAT;
c_MyBtn.SetMouseCursorHand();
c_MyBtn.EnableFullTextTooltip();
c_MyBtn.SetTooltip(_T("Some string"));
c_MyBtn.Invalidate();
```

So, does that function do something? The docs say it "Specifies whether to display the full text of a tooltip in a large tooltip window or a truncated version of the text in a small tooltip window", but the only thing I see is that tooltips don't show. I've tried long strings and strings with line breaks, but nothing.

Anyone knows the purpose of this function and how to use it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 SP1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wonderful thing about MFC is that Microsoft gives you the source. If there's ever a question, just look at the code.

Looking at `EnableFullTextTooltip`, all it does is set a couple of boolean flags. The important one is `m_bDelayFullTextTooltipSet`. This flag is checked in the `OnDraw` function. The tooltip text is set with `SetTooltip`: if the full button text fits on the button itself, it's called with NULL, otherwise it's called with the button text.

It appears the intent of this function is to have the tooltip display the text that should have been drawn on the button itself when the button is too small. If that's not what you want, avoid this function because it will override the tooltip that you have set.

Comment: Yes, I had looked, and reached the same conclusion, but didn't manage to make it work either. But now, after a whole night's sleep, I've made it work at the first try. And yes, it draws the whole caption in a tooltip if it doesn't fit in the button. But that's not what the docs say. That's one of the awful things about MFC, it often has a terrible documentation, sometimes outright misleading.