# CMFCButton::SetToolTip(str) not work in OnInitDialog() and

Tags: mfc

I want my `CMFCButton` to show tooltip when mouse over.
It doesn't work if I use `SetToolTip()` method in `OnInitDialog`

```
CMFCButton* bt = ((CMFCButton*)GetDlgItem(IDC_MFCBUTTON1)); 
bt->SetTooltip(_T("tooltip"));
```

BUT it does work if I put this code in message handle function like another button's click handle.
What I want is that the `CMFCButton` could show tooltip when the dialog is created, where should I put these code?

========================
By the way, The tooltip text I set in the Property view does not work for most time.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053302/what-does-cmfcbuttonenablefulltexttooltip-do

Answer (score 1):

I just derived a class

```
class CMyButton : public CMFCButton
{
public:
    void SetDelayFullTextTooltipSet(bool DelayFullTextTooltipSet)
    {
        m_bDelayFullTextTooltipSet = DelayFullTextTooltipSet;
    }
};
```

Instead of a `CMFCButton` variable on the Dialog class I use the button, I now have a `CMyButton`.

And in the `OnInitDialog`, after the `SetTooltip` call, I do

```
button.SetDelayFullTextTooltipSet(FALSE);
```

Comment: Can't we see a complete class here please?

Comment: This is the correct answer. Should be marked as such.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: It is the complete class; has no more than what is displayed here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called the base class' OnInitDialog()? The main point is that the control needs to be created before you call SetToolTip() on it. Step into OnInitDialog() with the debugger and see if m_hWnd of the control has a value at the moment you call SetToolTip().

Comment: Yes, I called the base class "OnInitDialog()" and the mfcButton's member m_pToolTip is valid.  The code bt->GetTooltipCtrl().GetText(str,bt) can get the right tooltip text I set in the property card, but it just cannot show unless I call setToolTip(str) after the dialog been created.